# java - stale reference to atomicintegerarray possible?

Tags: java, atomic

What happens when I assign a new instance of AtomicIntegerArray to a variable in a multithreaded environment?

```
AtomicIntegerArray array = new AtomicIntegerArray(...);
do some stuff
array = new AtomicIntegerArray(...);
```

Might some threads still access the stale reference to the old instance after the new assignment? If so, would I need to declare the atomic array as volatile as well?

Comment: is that code within a method? Or is it field declaration

Comment: It is a field declaration. At some point later, I may need to change the length of the array, hence a new instance with a new size.

Comment: @lgp, you are misunderstanding the semantics of AtomicIntegerArray. It doesn't maintain a reference to the original array. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicIntegerArray.html#AtomicIntegerArray%28int[]%29

Comment: @Dilum, what original array are you referring to? I'm not using a primitive int array to construct the AtomicIntegerArray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `array` is visible to other threads (e.g. a class member variable) then yes, it would need to be volatile as well.

Comment: @Reverend, that's not the point. The point here is that there is now a new instance of AtomicIntegerArray, and that some threads will be using it while some other threads may continue to use the old instance.

Comment: Yep. The point isn't access TO some elements of the array, but to the field reference itself. There can't be a guarantee from the Atomic classes themselves that their references are never stale (how should that work?) - volatile is very much necessary in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Your `array` variable appears to be a local variable, which by definition cannot be accessed by multiple threads.

However, if it's really an instance variable, then yes, other threads can see stale values, just like they can with any other instance variable. What an instance variable references does not affect how that instance variable is accessed.